# Create Currency Data Type C++

Tags: c++, integer, currency

my homework assignment is to create a class named Currency, using integers as the primitive type for dollars. And I must use these public methods I have.....
Now I removed the "cents" part, and the "subtration" part, because I'm assuming I can do those once I figure out how to do "Addition" for "Dollars" currency type.

No matter what I put into the "Currency Add(int Dollars);" I cannot get my code to work =.
I've done things like totalDollars += Dollars, return totalDollars, or just Dollars += Dollars, etc.

The output is always garbage : "-8353513636".
Or sometimes whatever number I put in the constructor.

I just can not seem to get it to PASS the number in and keep it there (Eventually want to make it hold a running total), and output it when I'm done. I've shortened up my code because the only problem with my code is the parts dealing with the "class"/currency data type. It just won't work.

At one point it told me it cannot convert from int to Currency data type

Here's the code I have so far:

```
/* Program By: 
    Date: 4/29/2011
    Class: 



*/

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <cmath>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

// Currency Class

class Currency
{
private:

    int Dollars;

public:
    Currency();
    Currency(int Dollars);
    Currency Add(int Dollars);
    int GetDollars();
};

Currency::Currency()
{
    Dollars = 0;
}

Currency::Currency(int Dollars)
{
}

// Add
Currency Currency::Add(int Dollars)
{ 
 // Have put totalDollars += Dollars, etc.
// Have also put a "return" value here.
}

int Currency::GetDollars()
{
    return Dollars;
}


int main()

{
    Currency payroll;

    int  currDollars;

    cout << "Please enter a dollar mount" << endl;
    cin >> currDollars;

    payroll.Add(currDollars);

    cout << "Current Amount is: " << payroll.GetDollars() << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

What am I doing wrong? I've been at this for several hours and I need to have it in by tomorrow =.
Help MUCH APPRECIATED!!!!

Comment: A few comments on style. It's better to use member initialization in the constructor, like `Currency::Currency(int Dollars) : Dollars(Dollars) {}`. And it'd be better to get rid of your default constructor and just use the `int` constructor with a default argument of 0. That would make the declaration in the class `Currency(int Dollars = 0);`

Answer (score 2):

Alright, we have a scoping issue here.

Since your parameter and member are both named Dollars, you need to use the this-Pointer to specify to which variable you would like to add.

```
this->Dollars += Dollars;
```

If you don't, the parameter hides the member, so you are effectively just adding the new amount to itself and then discarding it.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you!
I'll have to be more careful with naming.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some tips that might help:

In your Currency class, I would recommend using a naming convention so you can tell your member variables apart from arguments in the constructor and functions.  It seems like there might be some confusion in differentiating your `Dollars` member variable and the arguments that are also named `Dollars`.  One possible naming convention is to name you member variables "my" because they belong to the class.  There are other ways to handle this situation using the `this` pointer, but you may not have learned about pointers yet.

```
class Currency
{
private:

    int myDollars;

public:
    Currency();
    Currency(int dollars);
    void Add(int dollars); // changed this to return void - see below
    int GetDollars();
};
```

The other problem I see is that your functions that take the `int Dollars` argument don't seem to do anything with the argument value.  I know you're trying to figure out how to do this, so here's an example for the Add function.  For Add, I would just make it return void for now, so you don't have to deal with returning the `this` object from the function.

```
void Currency::Add(int dollars)
{ 
    myDollars += dollars;
}

int Currency::GetDollars()
{
    return myDollars;
}
```

I hope that helps a little.

Comment: That helped a ton, you and everyone else here are so helpful! I didn't expect so many great replies so soon, I should've posted this sooner! THANK YOU! 
Also glad to learn there's several ways as you and others pointed out to do this...just good to know, with the this pointer, the void, and the naming issue I had.
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you write code in C or C++, Java or any language, really, you need to pay attention to your variable names.

What's happened to you here is that you've used Dollars as the variable name inside the class, **and** in the function parameter. The parameter overrides the class and whatever you do to Dollars inside Add never has any affect on the Dollars variable inside the class.

Try renaming the Dollars parameter to something descriptive like `x`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! These little errors I make always seem to get me in big trouble. I'll have to remember this!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to return `Currency` in your `Add` function.

your `Add` function should look like this:

`void Currency::Add(int dollarsToAdd) {
    Dollars += dollarsToAdd;
}`

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of issues with your current code.

- You need two integers, of course, to store the data.
- Then a get function for each value.
- You I think you overcomplicated your Add function by trying to return a Currency. No need, just make it void and have it add the entered amounts to your integer values.
- You need to deal with cents overflowing past 100. E.g. 56 + 56 = 112 cents...
- You didn't mention data validation, that might need to be performed too. E.g. Disallow alpha and other garbage and do not allow cents values > 99 to be entered. etc.

Give this a try:

```
class Currency
{
private:
    int m_dollars;
    int m_cents;

public:
    Currency(int dollars, int cents);
    Currency Add(int dollars, int cents);
    int GetDollars();
    int GetCents();
};

Currency::Currency(int dollars, int cents) 
{ 
    m_dollars = dollars; 
    m_cents = cents;
}

Currency Currency::Add(int dollars, int cents)
{ 
    if (m_cents + cents >= 100) 
        return Currency(m_dollars + dollars + 1, m_cents + cents - 100);

    return Currency(m_dollars + dollars, m_cents + cents);
}

int Currency::GetDollars() { return m_dollars; }
int Currency::GetCents() { return m_cents; }

void main()
{
    int currDollars;
    int currCents;

    cout << "Please enter a whole dollar amount:" << endl;
    cin >> currDollars;

    cout << "Please enter a cents amount:" << endl;
    cin >> currCents;

    Currency payroll(currDollars, currCents);

    cout << "Current Amount is: " 
         << payroll.GetDollars() 
         << "."
         << payroll.GetCents()
         << endl;

    cout << "Please enter a whole dollar amount to add:" << endl;
    cin >> currDollars;

    cout << "Please enter cents to add:" << endl;
    cin >> currCents;

    payroll = payroll.Add(currDollars, currCents);

    cout << "Updated Amount is: " 
         << payroll.GetDollars() 
         << "."
         << payroll.GetCents()
         << endl;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the teacher wanted us to return a Currency, which confused me some (At least I think anyways).
I really appreciate the help!! Thank you!!! You even went ahead and did the cents for me...big time saver thank you! (Finals soon so time is important to me right now lol).
Already have the data validation, just cut it out so my code would be shorter.

Thank you so much for posting this code up! It's a huge help to me!
Everything is going smoothly now, thanks everyone!!

Comment: @Riotson: I think your teacher may have been wanting you to create a so-called immutable Currency class. See here for nice explanation: http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/01/13/immutable-types-understand-them-and-use-them/ I also updated my answer per your feedback and completion... Just for kicks. Good luck during finals!

Comment: Thank you! I've read some of that, I'll have to read the rest tonight before my test. Thank you so much for your help!! I was able to completely finish my assignment and get full credit :]. (Well with the exception of I forgot to add-in numeric error checking).
If it's not too much to ask....I now need to make an operator-overload version of it, and I've tried 2 operator overloads, but they only kind of work, and I'm lost as to where to go from there.
If you could give me any help with it I would greatly appreciate it, thank you!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853476/homework-operator-overloading-currency-class-stuck-lost